# How to pass argument to useSate's setState function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across this codePen 
https://codepen.io/enmanuelduran/pen/LgMomz while learning react. I tried to make a few changes and ended up with "Too many re-renders" error.

Instead of

```
const handleClick = () => setCount(count + 1);
```

I tried to pass argument to the handleClick function

```
const handleClick = (x) => setCount(x + count + 1);
```

and in my return statement I changed

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>
```

i added

```
<button onClick={handleClick(1)}>
```

when I run it I get

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Comment: const handleClick = (x) => setCount(x + 1); and <button onClick={handleClick}> should do the job correctly

Comment: @Tick20 this will not work because you are essentially doing `setCount(event + 1)`

Comment: @krisaoe, you are absolutely right, sorry for that, but the code which i meant to write is as const handleClick = () => setCount(x => x + 1); Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because here:

```
<button onClick={handleClick(1)}>
```

You are invoking `handleClick` immediately, not when the button is clicked, hence the function gets called on every render. This then triggers a re-render and you get your 'infinite' loop.

---

Try instead, an anonymous function that in turn calls your `handleClick`:

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
```

Or

```
<button onClick={e => handleClick(1)}>
```

If you need to utilise the event object, for example.

---

For what it's worth, the line that you had previously (`<button onClick={handleClick}>`) calls the `handleClick` function when the button is clicked, but passes the event object as the first argument.

Comment: why does ```handleClick(1)``` call the handleClick immediately? and how does having anonymous function resolve it?

Comment: `handleClick(1)` calls the handleClick function. When you write `onClick={handleClick(1)}`, you are passing the result of the `handleClick` function as a prop. This is not what you want. You want to pass the function as a prop, not the result of the function.

Comment: @JMadelaine That's actually a much nicer explanation than mine. Thanks.

Comment: Using the anonymous function means that you are passing a function definition, not calling a function.

Comment: @JMadelaine that clears it up. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>
```

this code mean that `onClick` refer to `handleChange` method

while

```
<button onClick={handleClick(1)}>
```

mean that `onClick` is set to the returned value of `handleClick`

---

to fix the errors set the value of`onClick` to function , like this

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `handleClick(1)` you are actually calling the function at that moment, which causes the function to re-call the `render` function and anyway to call the same function and so you enter an endless loop. To send the reference to a function (that is, the pointer), you have to write it like this:

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all other answers, note that when your state depends on the previous state value, mostly in case of counters where you need to do some calculations based on the old value, say an increment, it is advised to use the callback inside the setFuntion which is returned from useState, so in your case,

The below code could sometimes produce incorrect results as you are directly setting the value taking the old value from the state, which can sometimes be a not updated value between renders,

```
const handleClick = () => setCount(count + 1);
```

So to make sure everything works well, use the callback way as below,

```
const handleClick = () => setCount( prevCount => prevCount + 1);
```

where the above callback receives an argument with the previos state value.